# Random Freezes on B+

Tags: raspbian, failure

My Raspberry Pi B+ has started to freeze randomly for a few seconds only to continue as if nothing has happened.

I'm connecting over SSH only (no keyboard/monitor) and at least once a minute it will freeze for about 10-60 seconds.

I already have

- reinstalled the OS (now Linux raspy 3.18.13+)
- disconnected everything (only power/ethernet remain)
- changed the power adapter
- downgraded/upgraded the firmware

Is there anything else that could be the problem?

---

**Update:**

- Ping sometimes times out while it is unresponsive
- No messages in /var/log/syslog and dmesg

---

- trying different firmwares (with `rpi-update`) had no effect.

Comment: Are you running something that is CPU/memory intensive?

Comment: No, it's a fresh system with nothing on it.

Comment: You say you have changed the power supply, but have you actually measured the voltage http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Troubleshooting_power_problems

Comment: Try keeping 'top', 'ping', and 'watch "dmesg | tail" ' running to see if anything changes during or after the freeze.

Comment: Can you try keyboard and mouse with no network? I ask because the Pi has 10/100Mbit/s Ethernet and that can easily become saturated.

Comment: Have a look in `/var/log/syslog` immediately afterward to see if there is any explanation there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered I actually had two issues:

- slow when connecting to the Pi, this was solved by adding `UseDNS no` to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
- freeze during ssh - I had less issues after reinstalling the OS but after upgrading to *jessie* the freezes disappeared completely

Answer (score 1):

Your I/O could do such things. For example, if your SD card is slow and you start to do some writes, then your Linux session may be slow to process commands.
You will still be able to type commands, but execution may be delayed for several seconds during heavy writes.

In this case, if you have a slow SD card (Class 4 or slower), then I would try to upgrade to Class 10 and see if that will help.

Comment: It's already a class 10. But how could I find out if it's hanging because of IO? Is there a tool?

Comment: You can install atop, which also logs system stats. You can then Analyse tbose after a Freese. Atop's man page tells you how you do that.

Comment: The simplest way to check is to open a simple editor and see if the cursor moves fine while those "freeze ups". If it does, then your I/O is hitting hard. If your cursor freezes up too, that's something with network connectivity or CPU. I would try to perform the test locally to remove network out of picture.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a fresh install (without any firewall) check if you are not victim of a brut force attack by typing :

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/auth.log
```

If you see something like

> May 10 06:25:12 raspberrypi sshd[26518]: Failed password for root from
>   XX.XX.XX.XX port XXXX ssh2

then you should consider configure iptables and fail2ban...

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I hadn't thought of that. Unfortunately after closing ssh from outside and reinstalling the OS the issue still persists.